# missing mbstring extension

Tags: php, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 16.4 version.
Already I have switch php7 to php 5 version. 
I have an issue with phpmyadmin: when I visit localhost/php my admin it show

> "The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration."

how to solve this problem? 
plese help me

Comment: how is the issue described related to the title?

Comment: The mbstring extension is missing.please check the configuration

Comment: install mbstring then

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already answered on askubuntu : https://askubuntu.com/questions/772397/mbstring-is-missing-for-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: just google for "install mbstring ubuntu" if the question @rkosegi mentioned doesn't ffet your needs

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install the package for the PHP7 just write this commande in your shell

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

I hope it works for you.